# The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries,...., unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to combine the following 3 queries :

```
select distinct  
    col1 
from 
    [dbname] 

select  
    COUNT(*)col2  
from 
    [dbname]  
group by 
    col1 
order by 
    col1

select 
    (COUNT(**)-1) /  COUNT(distinct col3)
from 
    [dbname] 
group by 
    col1 
order by 
    col1
```

as :

```
select distinct col1 , 
        (select  COUNT(*)col2 from [dbname] group by col1 order by col1 )as something, 
        (select (COUNT(*)-1) /  COUNT(distinct col3)from [dbname] group by col1 order by col1) as something1 
from [dbname]
```

But I get the following error :

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

How to frame it properly?

Comment: As the message says you cannot use an `ORDER BY` in such subqueries (without `TOP` or `FOR XML`). And the result has to be one row (or now row) anyway, so an `ORDER BY` is pretty useless to unless the mentioned conditions are given. Please post the DDL of the tables, along with sample data and the expected result, to better point what you want here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `subquery` :

```
select col1, count(*) something1,
       count(*)-1 / (select count(distinct col3) from dbname where col1 = d.col1) something2
from dbname d
group by col1;
```

However, you can also directly warp it into single `SELECT` statement

```
select col1, count(*) something1,
       (count(*)-1 / count(distinct col3)) something2
from dbname d
group by col1;
```

**Edit:** Be aware with divide by zero error, so you can include `case` expression

```
select col1, count(*) something1,
       coalesce((count(*)-1/(case when count(distinct col3) = 0 
                                  then null else count(distinct col3) end)), 0) something2
from dbname d
group by col1;
```

Comment: @AnitaMathew... Add `case` expression to prevent divide by zero error.

Comment: Thaks..now that atleast gives some result..but the value i am getting for 1 of the records is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

looking to your queries seems you could use a single select avoinding subselect for column values

```
select col1, count(*) as col2, 
       (count(*)-1)/ count(distinct col3) as col_somethings
from [dbname]
group by col1 
order by col1
```

Comment: show me the exact error message .. and you actual query too